# Txt file not reading properly in Java

Tags: java

I am currently trying to read txt file which contains information of list of Subject and syllables of BscIT. But It reads only one word in one line.I have attached output which came in terminal.

[image]

---

And here is my code

---

---

Here is the method I created

```
class Course {
     public void Level(){
         System.out.println("Please Enter Your respective Levels and Subjects");
      }
}

class BBA extends Course{
     public void Level () {
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("BBA.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileReader);
            int c;
            while ((c = fileReader.read()) !=-1) {
                System.out.println((char)c);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
     }
 }

 class BscIT extends Course{
     public void Level () {
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("BscIT.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileReader);
            int c;
            while ((c = fileReader.read()) !=-1) {
                System.out.println((char)c);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
      }
  }
```

---

Here is the main method

```
public class Marks {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Course course = new Course();
        course.Level();
        System.out.println("1.BBA\t 2.BscIT");
        Scanner sr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice1 = sr.nextLine();
        while (!choice1.equals("1") && !choice1.equals("2")) {
            System.out.println("Enter a Valid number of Selection you want");
            choice1 = sr.nextLine();

        }
        if (choice1.equals("1")){
            Course cr = new BBA();
            cr.Level();
           
        }
        else {
            Course cr1 = new BscIT();
            cr1.Level();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: what is your expected output? how do you want it to be read?

Comment: Your code prints each character from the file on a newline with a `FileReader`. It isn't clear why you also have a `Scanner` there.

Comment: *"It reads only one word in one line"* No, it reads only one *character* at a time. The fact that each character is printed on separate lines is because *you* are calling `println()`. Try calling `print()` instead, so you don't print each character on new lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a Scanner then your code should probably be something like:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println( line );
}
```

and the text for the entire line will be read all at once.

If you don't want to read the entire line at once, then read the Scanner API for other methods that allow you to read the data.

Comment: For line-reading, it is much better to use `BufferedReader.readLine()`, because `Scanner.nextLine()` is insanely slow by comparison.